# Suggest a method for auto-updating my C# program

Tags: c#, auto-update

I need to keep a program I've written up to date, this will happen frequently over the next year or so, this will need to be done over the Internet. Where would you suggest I start, are there any common techniques? Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You can try Autoupdater.NET from [codeplex](http://autoupdaterdotnet.codeplex.com/) I developed it my self and it works very well in my applications. You just have to add one line in your code and its done.

Comment: [This article](https://omaha-consulting.com/best-update-frameworks-for-windows) gives an overview of the most popular solutions.

Answer (score 12):

Fairly well is not good enough :)

NAppUpdate is an open-source library I wrote to address just this. The general idea is to have the greatest flexibility, at the lowest overhead possible.

So, integration is super-easy, and the library does pretty much everything for you, including synchronizing operations. It is also highly flexible, and lets you determine what tasks to execute and on what conditions - you set the rules. Last by not least is the support for any updates source (web, BitTorrent, etc) and any feed format - whatever is not implemented you can just write by yourself.

Cold updates (requiring an application restart) are also supported, and done automatically unless "hot-swap" is specified for the task.

This all boils down to one DLL, less than 70kb in size.

More details at http://www.code972.com/blog/2010/08/nappupdate-application-auto-update-framework-for-dotnet/

Code is at http://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate (Licensed under the Apache 2.0 license)

Answer (score 9):

[ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) is perfect for this sort of scenario.

Comment: Problem with ClickOnce as I've just found out to my cost is that is won't work in a Terminal Services environment - see link here:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020945

Answer (score 7):

There is this great framework called [NetSparkle](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/) 
and also this  [DotNetUpdater](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx)

I haven't used them yet but hope to do so very soon. You can try it out.

Comment: So in other words, you just googled and found out about them.

Comment: That's the problem with providing links only: over time they're broken. @Shaikh Mohd. Nadeem, is DotNetUpdater still available nowadays and where to get information? (Google was not able to help on this occasion)

Answer (score 3):

ClickOnce is a good solution, but if you wish to have total control then you can roll-your-own. I would suggest polling a webservice to find if there are later versions available, downloading required files to a side-by-side directory, and using a launcher (or updating a shortcut) to automatically launch the latest version.

This is a little complicated, but caters for situations where the application may be running, and can therefore not be overwritten.

Comment: After creating my own application updater, I strongly suggest using ClickOnce.